# Django: can we alter filefield such that when a file is selected, it immediately gets uploaded

Tags: python, html, django, file-upload

I was just wondering: Will it be possible to alter the File Field such that when a file is selected, it immediately gets uploaded, without the means of additional button?

Assuming that I imported everything from .models, .forms, urls.py, etc successfully,

Codes in **models.py**:

```
class data(models.Model):
    Datas = models.FileField(upload_to='datas/upload')
```

Codes in **forms.py**:

```
class form1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = data
        fields = ('Datas',)
```

Codes in **views.py**:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'btnform1' in request.POST:
        newform1 = form1(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if newform1.is_valid():
            newform1.save()
            return redirect('list')
```

Codes in **upload.html**:

```
<h2>Data</h2>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
     {{newform1.as_p}}
<!--        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnform1">Upload Data</button>-->
     </form>
```

Can anyone guide me and possibly give a solution on how to do it if it is even possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you don't to change anything on backend but a javascript snippet to trigger form submit on change event of file field button. 
Assuming your input file field has id ="id_file" and form id="image-upload-form".

If your html looks like.

```
<form id="image-upload-form" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="id_Datas" type="file" id="id_datas">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnform1">Upload</button>
</form>
```

then js would look like.

```
$("#id_datas").on("change", function(event){
  $("#image-upload-form").submit();
});
```

Explaination:

See when you have a form in your html, a form role is to collect the data of input elements in it, and wrap this data and take the necessary method defined in form i.e. "GET", "POST" etc on the action defined which is a url like "/upload_file"

Now by default the form will only do this when the user clicks on button element with type submit contained within the form. Since you don't want this behaviour where user will have to click, you can also do via javascript, if you the html defined as above, then in order to test the behaviour you can select the file in the file upload option and go to developer console and run 
this

```
$("#image-upload-form").submit();
```

You will see the same behaviour happens when you click on the button as well. So we are doing this on `change` event to automatically submit the form when user selects a file.

Hope this helps, if not then let me know which part.

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite get it... Do u mind explaining a little bit more in depth?

Comment: Added some explanation and i hope you are using jquery.

Comment: Sorry, one last question. Where does the file get uploaded to?

Comment: there should be a folder inside media folder  this is controlled via upload_to='datas/upload'

Comment: Oh okay, I see what u mean. Thank you!